# What is the meaning of http://uri.etsi.org/TrstSvc/eSigDir-1999-93-EC-TrustedList/SvcInfoExt/RootCA-QC from ETSI TS 102 231 V3.1.2

Tags: cryptography, x509, pki

From Technical Spec

> http://uri.etsi.org/TrstSvc/eSigDir-1999-93-EC-TrustedList/SvcInfoExt/RootCA-QC
>
> a Root Certification Authority from which a certification path can be
> established down to a Certification Authority issuing Qualified
> Certificates. Only to be used as an extension, if the servicetype is
> http://uri.etsi.org/TrstSvc/Svctype/CA/QC

But what is the purpose of having this URI associated to a `TSPService` with `ServiceTypeIdentifier` http://uri.etsi.org/TrstSvc/Svctype/CA/QC?

Does it mean that if I have a prospective certificate path like this one:

```
 - A (root ca)
   - B (intermediate)
     - C (end user)
```

Where A is the only one registered in the TSL as a TSPService without the `http://uri.etsi.org/TrstSvc/eSigDir-1999-93-EC-TrustedList/SvcInfoExt/RootCA-QC` URI associated, I can't construct a valid certification path for `B` and `C`?